# Jmeter - replace value within json record

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm still new to aspects of jmeter and am trying to solve an issue I'm having.

I'm submitting a json record to an api endpoint.
The json contains a number of parameters including the following:

> {"StartTime":"1487869700",
>      "QueryEndTime":"12345678910",
>      "Terms":"ThingILookFor",
>      "Reason":"ReasonILook"
>   }
>
> I want to change this to be something like:
>
> {"StartTime":"1487869700",
>      "QueryEndTime":"endTime",
>      "Terms":"ThingILookFor",
>      "Reason":"ReasonILook"

The number string is an epoch value.
I want endTime to be a variable I can feed into the query body in the Http and specify at runtime.

My problem is that I need to change that epoch value at the time of query submission to the api to be the current epoch value.

I've tried using a Beanshell, but with no success.

This (probably very poor pseudo code) is what I want to do:

1. Read in my query body (obtained via a csv data config)
2. Replace the epoch string with the current epoch timestamp (I'm generating this via a function call in my User Defined Variables)
3. Submit editted query body via my http call

Obviously, any way to combine some of those steps would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the 'right' solution, but this is what I've done and it works:

1) Set up a user defined variable `currentEpoch`

2) Value of currentEpoch is `${__time(/1000,)}` as I require epoch in seconds

3) Replaced the value I want to replace in my test data (variable is "Query") with "replaceQueryStartTimeWithEpoch"

4) Set up a beanshell sampler with the following code in it:

```
vars.put("Query",vars.get("Query").replace("replaceQueryStartTimeWithEpoch", vars.get("currentEpoch")));
```

Happily this seems to work for what I need.

Would be interested to see some more 'elegant' solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [__time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function

> "QueryEndTime":"${__time(,)}"

Comment: Doesn't work. Will amend my question to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Separate system and I can't transfer stuff over. The issue is as I've descrived above. I need to replace a portion of my json record before I send it into a http request.

Comment: Just show your HTTP Request element. If you tried what I wrote, you had to change this